# Use aggregate to create a label from multiple shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, concatenation, aggregate, default-value

I'm trying to fill one field of a line feature shapefile Cables (CAVI) with a **default value** that updates based on the start coordinate end the end one. The resulting field is a combination of the id of the point feature shapefiles Junction (GIUNTO) and Termination (PTE) so that OBJECT_ID is like J1-T45 (I'm using **aggregate** and **intersect**).

AO(ARMADIO) is the Source of the network and directly connects to Junctions (GIUNTO).

Both Junction and Termination can be the start coordinate o the end coordinate of a Cable and there are Cables connecting two Junctions or two Terminations.

The issue I can't solve is when I have a cable transiting on multiple elements before reaching the end coordinate or when I have a cable connecting 2 Junctions or 2 Terminations. In those cases, I only get the '-' but not the star value or the end value.

So

- J1->T1: working if the line feature doesn't pass on any other J or another T.
- J1->J2: not working -> '-'
- T1->T2: not working -> '-'

Can you help to find the issue? I am new to QGIS so I might be using the functions the wrong way.

```
                concat(
        CASE 
            WHEN (
                aggregate(layer:='ARMADIO_OTTICO_87a77c7e_aea7_4cb8_91d4_ea945d23a900',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LONGITUDIN", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(x(start_point( $geometry)))
                )
                AND
                (
                aggregate(layer:='ARMADIO_OTTICO_87a77c7e_aea7_4cb8_91d4_ea945d23a900',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LATITUDINE", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(y(start_point( $geometry)))
                )
            THEN ('AO'

            )

            WHEN (
                aggregate(layer:='GIUNTI_5f52c93b_ac1e_4fba_8037_b5d91c89c1a8',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LONGITUDIN", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(x(start_point( $geometry)))
                )
                AND
                (
                aggregate(layer:='GIUNTI_5f52c93b_ac1e_4fba_8037_b5d91c89c1a8',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LATITUDINE", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(y(start_point( $geometry)))
                )
            THEN (

                aggregate(layer:='GIUNTI_5f52c93b_ac1e_4fba_8037_b5d91c89c1a8',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="OBJECT_ID", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:= (
                            (concat(x(start_point($geometry))) = concat(x(start_point(geometry(@parent)))))
                            and
                            (concat(y(start_point($geometry))) = concat(y(start_point(geometry(@parent)))))
                            )
                )
            )
            END
            ,'-',
            CASE 
            WHEN (
                aggregate(layer:='GIUNTI_5f52c93b_ac1e_4fba_8037_b5d91c89c1a8',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LONGITUDIN", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(x(end_point( $geometry)))
                )
                AND
                (
                aggregate(layer:='GIUNTI_5f52c93b_ac1e_4fba_8037_b5d91c89c1a8',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LATITUDINE", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(y(end_point( $geometry)))
                )
            THEN (

                aggregate(layer:='GIUNTI_5f52c93b_ac1e_4fba_8037_b5d91c89c1a8',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="OBJECT_ID", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
            )
            
            WHEN (
                aggregate(layer:='PTE_433c8795_a5e5_4892_bd7a_62b91b996f9d',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LONGITUDIN", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(x(end_point( $geometry)))
                )
                AND
                (
                aggregate(layer:='PTE_433c8795_a5e5_4892_bd7a_62b91b996f9d',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="LATITUDINE", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
                LIKE 
                concat(y(end_point( $geometry)))
                )
            THEN (

                aggregate(layer:='PTE_433c8795_a5e5_4892_bd7a_62b91b996f9d',
                  aggregate:='concatenate', 
                  expression:="ID_QUART_D", 
                  concatenator:='', 
                  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
            )
            
            END
```

)

[image: not-working]

AO -> J1 NOT WORKING (LINE FEATURE PASSING ON J1)

[image: ok]

J1 -> T1 WORKING

[image]

AO -> J2 WORKING (NOT PASSING ON ANY OTHER J)

[image]

J1 -> J2 NOT WORKING